# In $\mathbb{R}^3$, if $v$ is orthogonal to $x$ and $y$, then $x \times y$ is a scalar multiple of $v$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x, y, v \in \mathbb{R}^3$. If $v\neq0$ is orthogonal to $x$ and $y$, then $x \times y$ is a scalar multiple of $v$.

> We can do $$v\times(x\times y)=(v\cdot y)x-(v\cdot x)y=0$$ so, by definition of cross product, $v$ and $x\times y$ should be co-linear.

How can I see this in a more geometric way?

Comment: This is not true if $v \neq 0$ and either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$.

Comment: It is also not true if $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero and are scalar multiples of each other.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Provided that $x$ and $y$ are not parallel, what is the dimension of the space of vectors orthogonal to both $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Please explain a lil more

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you'd like explained?

Comment: I imagine the OP is unfamiliar with vector spaces and bases.

Comment: @Jason In that case, one can simply read the second half of the hint as, "how can one describe geometrically the set of $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that are orthogonal to both $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

If v is orthogonal to both x and y, then by definition:

$$ \vec v\cdot \vec x =0 $$ $$  \vec v\cdot \vec y = 0$$

Now, by definition $ x \times y$ is orthogonal to both x and y. Of course you could show this to be true, if you let some new vector $\vec q = \vec x\times \vec y$, then show that:

$$ \vec q\cdot \vec x = 0 $$ $$ \vec q\cdot \vec y = 0 $$

Now by equating the corresponding equations, we can see that if we introduce a new parameter t, that we have:

$$ \vec v\cdot \vec x + t \left( \vec q\cdot \vec x\right) = 0$$

And by distributivity we can have:

$$  \left( \vec v + t \vec q\right) \cdot \vec x  = 0$$

So we have shown that:

$$ \vec v = -t \vec q $$

so $\vec v$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec q $

Comment: I've only done x by the way, this works equally well for y. I just chose to use x.